# Dashes instead of slashes in razor/LINQ for dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this bit if code on my .cshtml page.

```
<a href='~/AudioFiles/@item.dateOfCall.ToShortDateString()_Store_Call.mp3' 
        class="btn btn-xs green tooltips" target="_blank" data-container="body" 
    data-placement="top" data-original-title="Play">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </a>
```

I need to change the date to be 2014-02-19

instead of 2014/02/19

Current the link breaks because it is trying to go to 2014/02/19 which is invalid in windows file naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the date like so:

```
<a href='~/AudioFiles/@item.dateOfCall.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")_Store_Call.mp3' 
    class="btn btn-xs green tooltips" target="_blank" data-container="body" 
data-placement="top" data-original-title="Play">
<i class="fa fa-play"></i>
</a>
```

For a full list of options check this page out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Bah!  I tried to do that with toShortDateString but it didn't work didn't even think about string.  Thanks.